# How to make faster a for Loop when Iterating between Bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Greatings, everybody! I'm making a small tool that Encrypts the Data of a File by Xoring all its bytes and after that, Encoding the Xor Result by using Base64. The problem begins when Looping between each Byte contained inside the File Data, this is how I've done:

````
int Initialization_Vector_Size = Initialization_Vector.Length;
string Crypto_String = null;

for(int Index = 0; Index < Input_Data_Size; Index++)
{
    int Single_Index = Index;
    byte Single_Byte = Input_Data[Single_Index];
    
    char Input_Character = Convert.ToChar(Single_Byte);
    int Input_Character_Code = (int)Input_Character;
    
    int Key_Index = Single_Index % Cipher_Key_Size;
    char Key_Character = Cipher_Key[Key_Index];
    
    int Cipher_Key_Code = (int)Key_Character;
    int Xor_Value = Input_Character_Code ^ Cipher_Key_Code;
    
    int IV_Index = Single_Index % Initialization_Vector_Size;
    char IV_Character = Initialization_Vector[IV_Index];
    
    int Initialization_Vector_Code = (int)IV_Character;
    int Crypto_Character_Code = Xor_Value ^ Initialization_Vector_Code;
    
    char Crypto_Character = (char)Crypto_Character_Code;
    char[] Characters_List = {Crypto_Character};
    
    string Security_Code = new String(Characters_List);
    Crypto_String += Security_Code;
}

byte[] Encrypted_Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Crypto_String);```
````

[image: Here you can see that Encrypting a Big file last around like 10 minutes and I would like to make it faster]

Comment: Briefly looking at this, I think the slowest part is probably the string concatenation. If you change it to using a `StringBuilder` to make the string, does that help?

Comment: Your benchmark result isn't meaningful without knowing what the input is and how you're timing it.  Also, maybe their performance impact is negligible, but, for readability sake, some of those variables can be removed (why does `Index` have to be copied to `Single_Index` before it can be used?  why does `Single_Byte` have to be converted a `char` before _that_ is converted to an `int`?).  On the matter of readability, I can no longer find an official Microsoft guide that speaks to this, but traditionally in C# local variables use camel case (`cryptoString` not `Crypto_String`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix that and see what's going on!

Comment: Is it faster to use a collection to store byte data and traverse it?